# ReactJS: Redirecting to a new page within an axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am building a MERN app with a login/register system and I am stuck on being able to redirect a user to a confirmation page which then prompts them to login.

It seems like I could use the `useHistory` hook in react-router-dom and do `history.push()` within my axios request which is within my register function:

```
function handleRegister(e) {
let history = useHistory();
e.preventDefault();

// Grab state
const user = {
  username: formState.username,
  email: formState.email,
  password: formState.password,
  password2: formState.password2,
};

// Post request to backend
axios
  .post("http://localhost:4000/register", user)
  .then((res) => {
   // Redirect user to the /thankyouForRegistering page which prompts them to login.
      history.push("/thankyouForRegistering");

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

}

But this does not work. I get an error back saying:

```
React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "handleRegister" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

Upon further research, it seems that in order to use the useHistory hook, it has to be within `<Router>`(possibly?) or directly on an onClick handler.

So something like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => history.push()}></button>
```

I can't really do that though, because I am not using onClick for my register button, I am using onSubmit and my own register function.

I also looked into using `<Redirect />`, so I tried making a new state called `authorized`, set the authorize state to true in my axios request, and then tried this:

```
<Route
            path="/thankyouForRegistering"
            render={() => (
              authorized ? (
                <ThankyouForRegistering />
              ) : (
                <Redirect to="/register" />
              ))
            }
          />
```

But this is not working either, and it also does not give me any kind of error.

Does anyone know the best way to redirect a user to a new page upon registering/logging in? I've been struggling with this for going on two weeks.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Here is the entire component - it's a bit messy but if anyone needs any explanations please let me know.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";


let navMenu;


function App() {
 let history = useHistory();
  const [navMenuOpen, setNavMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const initialState = {
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
  };
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState);
  const { username, email, password, password2 } = formState;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  function handleRegister(e) {
    //const history = useHistory();
    e.preventDefault();
    // Grab setState
    const user = {
      username: formState.username,
      email: formState.email,
      password: formState.password,
      password2: formState.password2,
    };

    // Post request to backend
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/register", user)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(user);
        history.push("/thankyouForRegistering");
        setAuthorized(true);
        // Redirect user to the /thankyouForRegistering page which prompts them to login.

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    // Once a user has registered, clear the registration form and redirect the user to a page that says thank you for registering, please login.
  }

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Grab setState
    const userData = {
      email: formState.email,
      password: formState.password,
    };

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/login", userData)
      .then((res) => {
        // Get token from local storage if there is a token
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
        // If there is a token, redirect user to their profile and give them access to
        // their recipeList and shoppingList
        setLoggedIn(true);
        //props.history.push("/profile");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const navMenuToggle = () => {
    console.log("toggle");
    setNavMenuOpen(!navMenuOpen);
  };

  const navMenuClose = () => {
    setNavMenuOpen(false);
  };

  const logoutFromNavMenu = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
    navMenuClose();
  };


  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar
          loggedIn={loggedIn}
          navMenuToggle={navMenuToggle}

        />
        <NavMenu
          loggedIn={loggedIn}
          show={navMenuOpen}
          navMenuClose={navMenuClose}
          logoutFromNavMenu={logoutFromNavMenu}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/login"
            render={(props) => (
              <Login
                handleLogin={handleLogin}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                email={email}
                password={password}
                errorMsg={errorMsg}
              />
            )}
          />

          <Route
            path="/register"
            render={(props) => (
              <Register
                handleRegister={handleRegister}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                email={email}
                username={username}
                password={password}
                password2={password2}
                errorMsg={errorMsg}
              />
            )}
          />

          <Route
            path="/profile"
            render={() => (loggedIn ? <Profile /> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}
          />

          <Route
            path="/thankyouForRegistering"
            render={() =>
              authorized ? (
                <ThankyouForRegistering />
              ) : (
                <Redirect to="/register" />
              )
            }
          />

          <Route
            path="/recipes"
            render={(props) =>
              loggedIn ? <RecipeBook /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/list"
            render={(props) =>
              loggedIn ? <ShoppingList /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />

          <Route
            path="/accountSettings"
            render={(props) =>
              loggedIn ? <AccountSettings /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
          />


          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => <Home isLoggedIn={loggedIn} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: move your line
let history = useHistory();
move this out of your function into react component.

Comment: In addition to that, please show your component definition instead of just the stuff inside it.

Comment: When I added let history = useHistory() out of my function, it gave me back this error: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Comment: Just posted the entire component.

Comment: Hey HappyPanda, did you tried with the props.history.push instead of useHistory() ?

Comment: Yep. I tried removing the let history = useHistory and did props.history.push and it gave me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I tried keeping let history = useHistory and doing props.history.push and it gave me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined". Both of these scenarios I passed props into my App component "function App(props)". At this point I feel like I am just trying random things without actually knowing what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. It wasn't enough to be using useHistory, I had to be using withRouter to get access to the history prop.

So I imported withRouter to my App component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then added this at the very bottom of the page, right below the App function:

```
const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

export default AppWithRouter;
```

So the App now must be exported as an argument of withRouter to get access to the history prop (as well as location and params I think?)

But this still wasn't enough. It was giving me an error saying that withRouter can only be used within `<Router />`(or `<BrowserRouter />`, whichever one you are using). So I wrapped my main `<App />` in index.js with `<BrowserRouter />`

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And imported it of course.

This still wasn't enough, though. After adding

```
history.push("/thankYouForRegistering);
```

to my axios request, it added the route to the URL, but it did not re render the view. It was still stuck on the register page. Then I realized I had `<BrowserRouter />` in two different places now. In my App component, I still had it wrapped around all of my routes, so after removing that and just returning a div with `<Switch />` wrapped around all of my routes, that made it work like expected.

I hope this helps somebody who is facing the same issue!